# node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok | node-gyp Error in React native - macOS

Tags: node.js, react-native

Failed to execute 'node-gyp configure --fallback-to-build --module=

warning " > jest-expo@40.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.13.1".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[13/16] ⡀ postinstall-prepare
[-/16] ⡀ waiting...
[-/16] ⡀ waiting...
[11/16] ⡀ canvas
error /Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@16.4.2 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v93-darwin-unknown-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v93-darwin-unknown-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v93-darwin-unknown-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for canvas@2.6.1 and node@16.4.2 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v93-darwin-unknown-x64.tar.gz
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.1.0
gyp info using node@16.4.2 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.1.0
gyp info using node@16.4.2 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.6 found at "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
(node:10666) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
gyp info spawn /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jashan.pj/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.4.2/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/jashan.pj/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.4.2',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/jashan.pj/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.4.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/Naico-RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'pixman-1' found gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp gyp ERR! configure error  gyp ERR! stack Error:` gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:353:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.4.2/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/Naico-RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v16.4.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.4.2/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.4.2/bin/node" "/Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jashan.pj/Documents/Projects/RN-Base-Architecture/node_modules/canvas
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.4.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

Answer (score 1):

This one helped me to solve this issue after trying different ways.

`brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg`

note -  if you don't have installed brew do it first. https://brew.sh/

Comment: After installing these I had to add the following two lines to `~/.zshrc` file:
`
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/jpeg/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/jpeg/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/jpeg/lib/pkgconfig"
`
And I was also getting another error related to chromium, if you are having this issue as well try this approach: [LINK](https://broddin.be/2022/09/19/fixing-the-chromium-binary-is-not-available-for-arm64/)